# C# - How to create a common method to update different properties in a object without creating multiple methods

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio, .net-core

**This is my object**

```
public class Totals {
        public int Total1 { get; set; }
        public int Total2 { get; set; }
        public int Total3 { get; set; }
        public int Total4 { get; set; }
    }
```

**Incrementing the values of Total1 and Total2 using calculateTotals method**

```
private Totals calculateTotals(Totals t) {
            if (//condition) {
                t.Total1 += 1;
            } else {
                 t.Total2 += 1;
            }
            return t;
        }
```

**Incrementing value of Total3 and Total4 of the same object with same conditions at a different location using different method calculateOtherTotals,  at this point I only need to update Total3 and Total4 **

```
private Totals calculateOtherTotals(Totals t) {
            if (//condition) {
                t.Total3 += 1;
            } else {
                 t.Total4 += 1;
            }
            return t;
        }
```

**I am new to c# , I need to increment the values Total1,Total2 and Total3,Total4 separately and the code which I have is working fine**

**Is there a way to improve my code?, how can I avoid creating two different methods which pretty much does the same logic on different properties? is there a way to create only 1 method to achieve my functionality?**

Comment: since they are `private`, why not just increment them using the properties directly ? something like `Total3++;`

Comment: What do these totals represent? Any time you find yourself using properties like `something1`, `something2`, and so you you should probably be using a collection.

Comment: @iSR5 - What's that got to do with being private? Are you assuming that these `private` methods are in the `Totals` class?

Comment: @Enigmativity yes, unless if they're outside the class, then this is something else.

Comment: It's really unclear what your functionality is that you're asking about.

Comment: _"Is there a way to improve my code?"_ - If the shown code is the all repetition you have I would say that it is ok. DRY yourself is a good principle but not a silver bullet and not a law and you should not apply it without thought. If there are only 2 such methods and they are not connected in any way other than "they look alike" (i.e. if your business requirements change for one method they should not be propagated to another) - I think you should leave it as is and do not bother with inventing something to save few lines of code.

Comment: @GuruStron - I think the OP has overly simplified the actual code to the point where we can't offer any sensible suggestions. The OP need to post real code (none of this `//condition` stuff) and then we can help.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it this way, but essentially the amount of code doesn't change.

This adds a judgment:

```
Totals calculateTotals(Totals t, bool Flag)
{
    //function1:
    if (Flag)
    {
        if (true)
        { //(condition) {
            t.Total1++;
        }
        else
        {
            t.Total2++;
        }
    }
    //function2:
    else
    {
        if (true)
        { //(condition) {
            t.Total3++;
        }
        else
        {
            t.Total4++;
        }
    }
    return t;
}
```

Call it like this:

```
Totals totals = new Totals();
totals.Total1=0;
totals.Total2=0;
totals.Total3=0;
totals.Total4=0;

calculateTotals(totals,true);//function1:
calculateTotals(totals,false);//function2:
```

Comment: Using a `bool Flag` is a good way to make the code confusing to understand. Two separate functions would be better. I think the OP needs to clarify the question before any decent answer can be given.

Comment: @Enigmativity  I can understand what you said, I just suggested a possibility as requested by the OP.

Answer (score 0):

Reflection is one way, though its slow and not a Domain Specific Language:

```
Type totalsType = typeof(Totals);
var totalToIncrement = condition;
PropertyInfo prop = totalsType.GetProperty("Total" + totalToIncrement);
prop.SetValue(null, 76);
```

Or perhaps you want to abstract the properties you're incrementing:

```
private Totals calculateTotals(Totals t)
{
    bool condition = true;
    AbstractAdds(ref t.Total1, ref t.Total2, condition);
    return t;
}

private void AbstractAdds(ref int a, ref int b, bool condition = false)
{
    if (condition)
    { 
        a++;
    }
    else
    { 
        b++;
    }
}

}

public class Totals
{
public int Total1;//{ get; set; }
public int Total2;//{ get; set; }
public int Total3;//{ get; set; }
public int Total4;//{ get; set; }
}
```

I'd personally have a `List<int>` or `int[3]` and make the condition calculate the index 0-3:

```
var index = calcCondition;
Totals[index]++;
```

This way its extensible for more totals and you get inbuilt functions like LINQ, eg `Totals.Sum()`.

Answer (score -1):

> Is there a way to improve my code?, how can I avoid creating two different methods which pretty much does the same logic on different properties? is there a way to create only 1 method to achieve my functionality?

Then it depends on how you want your method (function) to be. (E.g., how you define what your function will do and how your class and properties are characteristic—which, currently, many who want to help you still wonder about.)

Let me give another clear example.

Assume that you answer your additional requirement are:

- My object has only 4 properties of "Total"
- I want these new function to increment value only 1 when call, no need to add more than 1
- This function is called from another class to modify my object value
- I want my cool function name `calculateOtherTotals` being private, because of some unexplained reason such as “I don't like others knowing it exists”.

Then

```
public OtherClass{
    Public Totals ExposeThePrivateCalculateOtherTotals(Totals t, bool IncrementT1 , bool IncrementT2 , bool IncrementT3, bool IncrementT4)
    {
         calculateOtherTotals(t, IncrementT1 , IncrementT2 , IncrementT3,  IncrementT4);
    }
    Private Totals calculateOtherTotals(Totals t, bool IncrementT1 , bool IncrementT2 , bool IncrementT3, bool IncrementT4) {
        
        if( IncrementT1 )  t.Total1 += 1; //choose your style
        if( IncrementT2==true )  ++t.Total2;//choose your style
        if( IncrementT3!=false )  t.Total3++; //choose your style
          t.Total4 +=  IncrementT4==true?1:0;//choose your style
        return t;
    }

}

//In main (how to use)

Totals t= new Totals();

OtherClass doMyFunc = new OtherClass();
t = doMyFunc.ExposeThePrivateCalculateOtherTotals(t, true, false,false,false); // result of operation => t.total1 += 1;
t = doMyFunc.ExposeThePrivateCalculateOtherTotals(t, false, true,false,false); // result of operation => t.total2 += 1;
```

Comment: Thank for the edit , sorry about my English skill.